# Criar um gráfico de caracteres em python

Tags: python

Olá,
sou um novato e estou tentando fazer um programa que irá receber uma lista de números e plotar um gráfico usando | para marcar o valor do número naquela posição e o gráfico é todo contornado com *.
Exemplo:3 2 1

'****

***|  *

*|| *

*|||**
***** '

No momento eu tenho esse código, mas estou sem muita ideia de como eu digo para o python plotar esse gráfico. No caso n é o tamanho da lista e ma o maior valor da lista.

```
def grafico(lista):
    maior(lista,n)
    print('*'*(n+2)+'\n*'*(ma+2))
    return
```

Answer (score 2):

Se quer fazer isso pra aprender, e como exercício - é algo bem legal - e vou explicar aqui.

Se precisa disso como um requisito para um aplicativo de trabalho/produção, meu projeto pessoal no último ano tem sido uma biblioteca que permite justamente desenhar com caracteres - e pode ser indicada para o caso.

Então, no primeiro caso: a moldura precisa ter o tamanho do maior valor da lista, e mais 2 colunas: uma para o contorno a direita, outro para o contorno a esquerda.

Esse tamanho vai ser a quantidade de "*" no começo e no final da impressão.

Mais que isso, é só saber que a multiplicação `*` de uma string por um inteiro funciona, então se quero tornar o número "5" numa sequência de "|||||", é só fazer `"|"* 5` em Python, e que as strings em Python tem os métodos `.ljust` e `.rjust` que permitem adicionar caracteres de preenchimento a direita, ou a esquerda conform o valor desejado.

A função `max` do Python também retona o maior valor da lista de forma trivial.
E, claro, uma vez que saibamos o que queremos fazer, é só encapsular tudo em uma função - como você já fez.

```py
def grafico(lista):
    maior = max(lista)
    largura = maior + 2
    print("*" * largura)
    for valor in lista:
        print("*", ("|" * valor).ljust(maior), "*", sep="")
    print("*" * largura)
```

E no modo interativo, o resultado é esse:

```
In [26]: grafico([2,3,5,1,6,3,3,4,2])                                                                                  
********
*||    *
*|||   *
*||||| *
*|     *
*||||||*
*|||   *
*|||   *
*||||  *
*||    *
********
```

---

## Usando uma biblioteca gráfica para o terminal - terminedia

Como descrevi acima, outra forma de fazer é usando uma lib para desenho com texto - no caso a biblioteca `terminedia` (disclaimer: sou o autor e principal contribuidor).

Para instala-la em seu ambiente de Python, basta fazer  `pip install terminedia` -
la prove chamadas para desenhar retas e retângulos com os caracteres desejados - mas a lógica continua ficando a cargo de quem faz o programa.

Com a terminedia disponível a mesma função pode ficar:

```py
def grafico(lista, pos=(0, 0)):
    maior = max(lista)
    largura = maior + 2
    pos = TM.V2(pos)
    with TM.Screen() as sc:
        for i, valor in enumerate(lista):
            sc.draw.line(pos + (1, i), pos + (valor, i), char="|", color="green")
        sc.draw.rect(pos, (pos[0] + maior + 1, pos[1] + len(lista) + 1), char="*", color="#f0f")
        TM.pause()
```

O programa fica maior, mas usando isso, já apaga a tela, aguarda qualquer tecla no final (a chamada ao `terminedia.pause()` ) - e, se precisar de mais funcionalidades, você pode voltar e imprimir coisas mais pra cima - bastando passar as coordenadas "x, y" desejadas . O exemplo também usa cores - verde e roxo  - mas a versão que está publicada da lib ainda não funciona com cores no windows
(elas funcionam bem no Mac e no Linux).
Se optar por experimentar a lib, provavelmente vai gostar do método `.print_at`  do objeto `Screen` (no código acima poderia ser usado como `sc.print_at((x, y), "texto")`
E usamos os caracteres que você passou na pergunta, mas por padrão ela desenha com caracteres de bloco -  `'█'`. Dá pra fazer:

```py
def grafico(lista, legendax, legenday, pos=(0, 0)):
    maior = max(lista)
    largura = maior + 2
    pos = TM.V2(pos)
    with TM.Screen() as sc:
        for i, valor in enumerate(lista):
            sc.draw.line(pos + (1, i), pos + (valor, i), char="\N{BLACK VERTICAL RECTANGLE}",  color="green")
        sc.draw.rect(pos, (pos[0] + maior + 3, pos[1] + len(lista) + 1), color="#f0f")
        sc.print_at(pos + (0, len(lista) + 1) , legendax)
        sc.print_at(pos + (-2, len(lista) - len(legenday) ), legenday, direction=TM.Directions.DOWN)
        TM.pause()
```

Com a função acima, a chamada

```
grafico([2,3,5,1,6,3,3,4,2], pos=(10,10), legendax="unidades", legenday="meses")
```

Produz este resultado (no terminal de texto, não é uma janela gráfica):

[image: Saida no terminal da função "grafico" usando legendas e caracteres de bloco]

Comment: Muito obrigado jsbueno, ajudou bastantão.